# React router changing path but not rendering component

Tags: javascript, reactjs, react-router-dom

I'm working on creating a customer page where they can see their quote and/or modify it.  After they are happy with the quote that they have, they can accept it and it will bring them to a success page.  I have the routes set up and the components created, but for some reason when I click the `Link` component within my CustomerHome page, it changes the path in the url but doesn't ever renders my success page.

CustomerHome.js

```
import React from 'react';
import { Link } from 'react-router-dom';
import Button from '../../components/Spinner/Button';
import '../../StyleSheets/AdContract.css';
import '../../StyleSheets/Button.css';

export default class CustomerPage extends React.Component{
    constructor(props){
        super(props);

        this.state = {
            QuoteID: this.props.match.params.id,
            CustomerFirst: "",
            CustomerLast: "",

        }
    }

    componentDidMount(){
        socket.emit('SelectCustomerQuote', this.props.match.params.id, function(result){
            this.setState({
                CustomerFirst: result[0].CustomerFirst,
                CustomerLast: result[0].CustomerLast,
            })
        }.bind(this));
    }

    AcceptedQuote(){
        console.log("Quote Accepted");
    }


    render(){
        return(
            <div id="CustomerContainer" style={{width: '100%', height: '100%'}}>
                <div id="CustomerContent" className="fade-in" style={{textAlign: 'center', width: '100%', height: '100%'}}>
                    <div id="Welcome" style={{marginTop: '15%'}}>
                        <p style={{fontSize: '35px', fontWeight: 'bold'}}>Hello, {this.state.CustomerFirst + " " + this.state.CustomerLast}</p>
                        <p style={{fontSize: '20px', color: 'orange'}}><b>Your Quote Is Ready!</b></p>
                    </div>

                    <div>
                        {/*<Button click={this.AcceptedQuote.bind(this)} name="Accept Quote" color="G-green"></Button>*/}
                        <Link className="ButtonUI G-green" to="/customer/success">Accept Quote</Link>
                    </div>
                </div>
            </div>
        )
    }
}
```

Index.js

```
import 'core-js/es6/map';
import 'core-js/es6/set';
import 'core-js/fn/array/find';
import 'core-js/fn/array/includes';
import 'core-js/fn/number/is-nan';
import React from 'react';
import ReactDOM from 'react-dom';
import './index.css';
import App from './App';

import CustomerPage from './imports/CustomerPage/CustomerHome.js';
import CustomerSuccess from './imports/CustomerPage/CustomerSuccess.js';

import { BrowserRouter, Route, Link, Switch } from 'react-router-dom' 

ReactDOM.render((
    <BrowserRouter>
        <Switch>
            <Route exact path='/' component={App} />
            <Route path='/customer/:id' component={CustomerPage} />
            <Route path='/customer/success' component={CustomerSuccess} />
        </Switch>
    </BrowserRouter>), document.getElementById('appRoot'));
```

CustomerSuccess.js

```
import React from 'react';

export default class CustomerSuccess extends React.Component{
    constructor(props){
        super(props);

        this.state = {

        }
    }

    render(){
        return(
            <div>
                Success!
            </div>
        )
    }
}
```

I'm not completely familiar with how react router works, so maybe I'm just missing something simple here, or doing something completely wrong.  If anyone could give me some ideas or suggestions as to what they think my issue might be, I would appreciate it! Thanks.

Comment: Try changing the order. I think /customer/:id is matching (with the :id set to 'success'). Put /customer/success first, then it will match that, and go to the other route for anything else.

Comment: @CalIrvine ok I will give that a shot.

Comment: @CalIrvine that did the trick, thank you!

Comment: you are welcome

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Because of the order of your Routes

```
    <Route path='/customer/:id' component={CustomerPage} />
    <Route path='/customer/success' component={CustomerSuccess} />
```

/customer/:id will match for /customer/success and set the id param to the string 'success'

If you change the order of your routes to put /success first (and any other routes that don't have parameters) it should work fine.

From the docs

> A Switch looks through all its children 
>             elements and renders the first one whose path
>             matches the current URL. Use a  any time
>             you have multiple routes, but you want only one
>             of them to render at a time.

Comment: Or we can use the exact keyword.

Comment: @ZunaibImtiaz It's a good idea to use the exact keyword as well, but I believe you will still have the same problem. As the /:param route will match first, it won't reach your /success Route, whether it is flagged exact or not.